# Kafka Connect - JDBC Sink connector - tries to add AvroConverter Schema Registry details into target table as new columns

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to load data from Kafka Cluster into Oracle DB. Data in cluster has been loaded using AvroConverter and the schema details contains also fields like source, op, ts_ms etc. My issue here is that when I'm trying to read data from the cluster then it tries to add these schema fields into my destination table as additional columns and throws an error:

```
 INFO Unable to find fields [SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{Tab1.Value:STRUCT}, name='after', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{Tab1.Value:STRUCT}, name='before', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRING}, name='op', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRUCT}, name='transaction', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{INT64}, name='ts_ms', isPrimaryKey=false}] among column names [col1, col2, col3, col4] (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure)
[2022-04-10 17:18:04,181] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-conn} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Cannot ALTER TABLE "Tab1" to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.TableAlterOrCreateException: Cannot ALTER TABLE "Tab1" to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.amendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:182)
```

I will put below my connector details (run in a docker container, connection strings removed for clarity):

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-conn",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "name": "jdbc-conn",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics.regex": "customer.*",
    "transforms": "changeTopicName",
    "transforms.changeTopicName.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.changeTopicName.regex": "customer.(.*)",
    "transforms.changeTopicName.replacement": "$1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@localhost:1521:customer",
    "connection.user": "user",
    "connection.password": "pass",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": ""
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

Docker container

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest

RUN   confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
```

initialised with

```
docker run -d \
  --name=connect \
  --net=host \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="localhost:9092" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_CONSUMER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="localhost:9092" \
  -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="localhost:9092" \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="sink_group1" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="connect-sink-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR="3" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_PARTITIONS="3" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="connect-sink-configs" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR="3" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="connect-sink-status" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR="3" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO="xxx" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="yyy" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO="xxx" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="yyy" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="localhost:9092" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
  -e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL="INFO" \
  -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components \
  -v /home/cdcadmin/oracle_dest_connector/mounted/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars \
  jdbc-conn:latest
```

I do not want to add these fields at all.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the schema details contains also fields like source, op, ts_ms etc

You need to install and configure the Debezium ExtractNewState transform to remove those.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer. I did try this but with "moderate" success, meaning no success. Could you please suggest which transformation I need to apply, like ExtractField or Flatten? I tried both of these. What else I might use? An extra difficulty for me is that there is no more unwrap in this, replaced with flatten, and I'm missing a detailed docs about it.

Comment: Unclear why you need to use the Flatten transform. That doesn't remove any fields

Comment: I don't want to use Flatten. I was trying to "flatten" a message and extract fields. My only goal is to fetch data from Kafka Cluster, Avro format pushed by Debezium Oracle connector, and insert it into Oracle DB without any additional columns like source, op, etc. Could you please suggest the best approach, using ExtractNewState extraction?

Comment: You don't need to repeat your question. What issues are you having with the transform I've linked to? This is what will remove those fields

Comment: 1/2 Now I have issues with installing transformations.
Dockerfile
```
RUN   confluent-hub install --no-prompt jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common:latest
COPY mounted/debezium-scripting-1.9.0.Final.jar /etc/kafka-connect/jars/
```
in logs from docker
```
INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.Filter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
```

Comment: 2/2 In config:
"transforms": "changeTopicName,unwrap",
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
"transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
"transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
"transforms.unwrap.addfields": "op,table,source,ts_ms",
And error message:
Invalid value io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState for configuration transforms.unwrap.type: Class io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState could not be found.

Comment: The logs only say the Filter transform was added, not the extract one

Comment: I know, but there is nothing more in logs about io.debezium.transforms.* . I have added debezium-scripting-1.9.0.Final.jar, what else I'm missing here?

Comment: You can see here that this Extract transform is not part of the scripting module code, so I'm not sure how that's relevant to the problem. https://github.com/debezium/debezium/tree/main/debezium-scripting/src/main/java/io/debezium/transforms The `debezium-core` one is the JAR you should care about. More specifically, you should just use Confluent hub to install all of Debezium, not only copy single JAR files around. Or you can use Debezium docker images rather than Confluent ones

Answer (score 0):

The answer and comments from OneCricketeer to use
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html

solved the issue. What I was missing is debezium-core properly installed. I hoped that ExtractNewRecordState is part of confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc but it isin't. Since I need to stick with confluent-hub I decided to install debezium/debezium-connector-mysql (there is no Debezium Oracle connector available on confluent-hub).
My Dockerfile is now:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest

RUN   confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
RUN   confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:latest
```

and logs finaly say:

```
 INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState'
```

The "Unable to find fields" error is solved.

Now I've hit another one:)
"Error: Unsupported source data type: STRUCT" but this is a different issue now. Thanks again.